# How resolve and reject using angular $q

Tags: angularjs

I have a Angular service with below signature

```
function test(param1, param2, param3) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   if(!param1 || !param2) {
       deferred.reject();
       return deferred;
   } else {
       deferred.resolve();
   }

   var helper1 = function(){};
   var helper2 = function(){};

   return deferred;
}
```

And when called

```
test().then(function(){ }, function(){ });
```

Resolved or Rejected are not executed. Anything wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return promise from deffer object.

```
 function test(param1, param2, param3) {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       if(!param1 || !param2) {
           deferred.reject();
       } else {
           deferred.resolve();
       }

       var helper1 = function(){};
       var helper2 = function(){};

       return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Still it is not calling resolve or reject handler inside then.

Comment: your are calling reject or resolve before handling. Use promise when you have something on timer, or some server call. In your case ideally there is no need to create promise..

Comment: But then should be executed still if it is resolved or rejected already right?

Comment: I am sorry it was my mistake. Thanks. Whole thing is working as expected now.

Comment: your example will work, just return promise instead of deffer object. It you resolve promise before handling it, then also it will call your handler.